# Show that the Lebesgue integral remains a monotone operation in $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mathcal{L}^0$ be the set of all measurable functions, $\mathcal{L}^1$ be the set of all integrable functions in $\mathcal{L}^0$ and $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$ the set of all functions $f\in \mathcal{L}^0$ with $f^-\in \mathcal{L}^1$

we set 
$$\int fd\mu=\int f^+d\mu-\int f^-d\mu\in(-\infty,\infty], \text{ for } f\in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$$

How do I show that the Lebesgue integral remains a monotone operation in $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$?

I think I need to show:

If $f\in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$ and $g\in \mathcal{L}^0$ are such that $g(x)\geq f(x)$, for all $x\in S$, then $g\in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$ and $\int gd\mu\geq \int fd\mu$.

- Is that a correct approach?
- If so how do I show this?
- If not what is a good approach?

Comment: Think about the relations between $f^+$ and $g^+$, and between $f^-$ and $g^-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably, if one shall prove that the integral is monotone on $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$, one can assume from the start that both, $f$ and $g$, belong to $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$ rather than deducing $g \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$ from $f \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1},\, g \in \mathcal{L}^0$ and $f \leqslant g$.

There's nothing wrong with doing the latter, though.

Note that for any functions $f,g$ the inequality $f \leqslant g$ implies

\begin{align}
f^+ &\leqslant g^+,\text{ and} \tag{1}\\
g^- &\leqslant f^-. \tag{2}
\end{align}

For measurable $g$ and $f \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$, one can easily deduce $g \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$ and

$$\int f\,d\mu \leqslant \int g\,d\mu\tag{3}$$

from $(1)$ and $(2)$.

From $0 \leqslant g^- \leqslant f^-$ and $f^- \in \mathcal{L}^1$ it follows that $g^- \in \mathcal{L}^1$, and hence $g \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$.

Adding $(1)$ and $(2)$ and integrating yields

$$\int f^+\,d\mu + \int g^-\,d\mu \leqslant \int g^+\,d\mu + \int f^-\,d\mu\tag{4}$$

by the monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral for non-negative functions. Subtracting the finite value $\int g^-\,d\mu + \int f^-\,d\mu$ from $(4)$ yields $(3)$.

Comment: Thanks. I am still having trouble showing $g\in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$, specifically showing $\int g^+d\mu<\infty$, as I understand a function $g\in \mathcal{L}^0$ is said to be integrable if $\int g^+d\mu<\infty$ and $\int g^-d\mu<\infty$. Furthermore, if $\int g^+d\mu=+\infty$ as you stated in one case then $g$ is not integrable so how can I say $\int fd\mu\leq \int g d\mu<$?

Comment: But for $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$, we don't need $\int g^+\,d\mu < +\infty$, we only have a finiteness condition for the negative part. And $g^- \in \mathcal{L}^1$ follows since $0 \leqslant g^- \leqslant f^-$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. and what about the integrability of $g$?

Comment: $g$ may or may not be integrable in the sense $g \in \mathcal{L}^1$. But the integral makes sense for functions in $\mathcal{L}^{0-1}$. Since $0 \leqslant \int g^-\,d\mu < +\infty$, we don't get an indeterminate form $\infty - \infty$ from $\int g^+\,d\mu - \int g^-\,d\mu$, so $\int g\,d\mu = \int g^+\,d\mu - \int g^-\,d\mu$ is well-defined. We have $g \in \mathcal{L}^1 \iff \int g^+\,d\mu < +\infty$ for $g \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$, and $\int g\,d\mu = +\infty$ if (and only if) $g^+ \notin \mathcal{L}^1$.

Comment: If $g\notin \mathcal{L}^1$ is it obvious $\int fd\mu\leq \int gd\mu$? since $\int gd\mu=\infty$?

Comment: If $g\notin \mathcal{L}^1$ (but $g \in \mathcal{L}^{0-1}$), then $\int g\,d\mu = +\infty$. And $\int f\,d\mu \leqslant +\infty$ is clear, I think.